# what is dimension of vector space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimnesion space and $A$ and $B$ two linear transformation of $V$ in itself such that $A^2=B^2=0$ and $AB+BA=I$

I don't even have any idea how to start the question,please provide me a hint so  that i can try to solve
.

Thankyou

Comment: Have you tried using the rank nullity theorem?

Comment: ok , here A and B  are  Nilpotent matrix ,so the rank of $A$ can be atmost $\frac{n}{2}$.

Comment: No ,i have no idea how to use rank naullity theorem .

Comment: Observe you want $(A+B)^2=I.$ So $A+B$ has to be it own inverse. Just an observation, I don't see how this may help.

Answer (score 1):

The vector space $V$ can have every even finite dimension $n\ge 2$. It is enough to find two $2\times 2$-matrices for this. Take
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},\;
B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \cr 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Clearly $A^2=B^2=0$ and $AB+BA=I$.

Comment: form this example how can we conclude about dimension of $V$?

Comment: Here $\dim V=2$, right? But we can build $2\times 2$ block matrices of every size $2m$ form $A$ and $B$.